# JS function that calculates products qty and options additional taxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this complicated JS function that must calculate the sum of product single price * qty and if there are available options for the product and if the available options have extra tax it has to be added also to the total.

```
function update_amounts() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#basketorder > tbody  > .product').each(function () {
        var qty = $(this).find('.qty option:selected').val();

        var selectedoptaddtax = 0.0;
        $('.selectedoptionselect option:selected').each(function () {
            var selectedoptaddtax = $(this).attr('price');
        })

        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var amount = ((qty * price) + selectedoptaddtax);
        sum += amount;
        $(this).find('.amount').text('' + amount);
    });
    $('.total').text(sum);
}
```

I have prepared jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xs1hL39k/2/)

In the example I have only 1 product in the basket, but the function must calculate correct if more that 1 product in the basket.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    update_amounts();
    $('.qty').change(function () {
        update_amounts();
    });
    $('.selectedoptionselect').change(function () {
        update_amounts();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you need this http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/9a50bhpv/1/

Comment: So basically your Problem is,that the extra Costs From the `options` are beeing ignored ?

Comment: Satpal thanks, first of all, but if you add 2 as quantity your function doesnt calculate correct.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add selected option prices.

*Code*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectedoptionselect, .qty').change(function () {
        update_amounts();
    }).change();
});

function update_amounts() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#basketorder > tbody  > .product').each(function () {
        var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();

        var selectedoptaddtax = 0.0;

        //Use find here
        $(this).find('.selectedoptionselect option:selected').each(function () {
            selectedoptaddtax += +$(this).attr('price'); // You need to add price
        })

        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();

        var amount = (qty * price) + (qty * selectedoptaddtax); //Changes here

        sum += amount;
        $(this).find('.amount').text('' + amount);
    });
    $('.total').text(sum);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/qvwah1kp/)

Comment: Great Man ! Thanks, it works, but would it works if I add few more products with their options?

Comment: once again - huge Thank you ! :)